# Zod - Accessing value from a field in SchemaA to use in SchemaB?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, zod

I'm trying to do some processing of my incoming data in my Zod schema, and am trying to use the resulting value of a field in one schema to calculate the value of a field in another.

i.e.

```
// Need to use totalValuation's actual value from Schema 2
// to calculate the value for percentageOfValuation in Schema 1


const Schema1 = z.object({
    valuation: z.number().transform((value) => ({
        valuation: value,
        percentageOfTotalValue: `${(value / totalValuation)*100}%`
    }))
})

const Schema2 = z.object({
    totalValuation: z.number(),
    subAccounts: z.array(Schema1)
})
```

Example of intended result:

```
Schema2.parse(data) === {
    totalValuation: 200,
    subAccounts: [
        {
            valuation: 20,
            percentageOfTotalValue: '10%',
        },
        {
            valuation: 80,
            percentageOfTotalValue: '40%',
        },
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to somehow access `totalValuation` in Schema2 in order to calculate what `percentageOfTotalValue` should be?

I assume the usage of Schema1 within Schema2 might make things harder also. Would be ideal if it could be solved as is, but if they need to be combined into one schema or something else to make this work then that would be okay.

Comment: What does the _input_ look like? What is the format of `data`?

Comment: How is 200 supposed to be derived from 20 and 80? Did you mean 100?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `totalValuation` in `Schema1` because `Schema1` doesn't have an object property with that name. You should move the `.transform()` from `Schema1` to `Schema2`.

It's difficult to know what you are specifically looking for as you didn't provide sample input. Two guesses:

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const Schema = z
  .object({
    totalValuation: z.number(),
    valuations: z.number().array(),
  })
  .transform(({ totalValuation, valuations }) => ({
    totalValuation,
    subAccounts: valuations.map((valuation) => ({
      valuation,
      percentageOfTotalValue: `${(valuation / totalValuation) * 100}%`,
    })),
  }))

const data = { totalValuation: 200, valuations: [20, 80] }
Schema.parse(data)
//=> {
//     totalValuation: 200,
//     subAccounts: [
//       { valuation: 20, percentageOfTotalValue: "10%" },
//       { valuation: 80, percentageOfTotalValue: "40%" }
//     ]
//   }
```

```
import { z } from 'zod'

const Schema = z
  .array(z.object({ valuation: z.number() }))
  .transform((valuations) => {
    const totalValuation = valuations.reduce(
      (sum, { valuation }) => sum + valuation,
      0
    )
    return {
      totalValuation,
      subAccounts: valuations.map(({ valuation }) => ({
        valuation,
        percentageOfTotalValue: `${(valuation / totalValuation) * 100}%`,
      })),
    }
  })

const data = [{ valuation: 20 }, { valuation: 80 }, { valuation: 100 }]
Schema.parse(data)
//=> {
//     totalValuation: 200,
//     subAccounts: [
//       { valuation: 20, percentageOfTotalValue: "10%" },
//       { valuation: 80, percentageOfTotalValue: "40%" },
//       { valuation: 100, percentageOfTotalValue: "50%" }
//     ]
//   }
```